# SQLite subquery math returns wrong values

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, subquery

I'm querying a database to calculate percentages of calls by state. The first query pulls data correctly but when I try to do the needed math it doesn't return the correct values.

```
SELECT state, count(call) as Calls, (Select count(call) FROM test) as TotalCalls
FROM test
WHERE state IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY state
ORDER state ASC;

State    Calls    TotalCalls
-----    -----    ----------
Alabama   416       32149
Alaska     31       32149
Arizona   685       32149
Arkansas  216       32149
```

Now changing the query to do the math it returns 0.  Answers for the first three should be 1.29, 0.09, 2.13

```
SELECT state, ROUND((count(call)/(Select count(call) FROM test) * 100.00), 2) AS StatePct
FROM test
WHERE state IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY state
ORDER BY state ASC;

State     StatePct
-----     --------
Alabama     0.0
Alaska      0.0
Arizona     0.0
Arkansas    0.0
California  0.0
Colorado    0.0
```

Thinking that my SQL wasn't malformed, I reversed the calculations and it works!

```
SELECT state, ROUND(((Select count(call) FROM test)/count(call) * 100.00), 2) AS StatePct
FROM test
WHERE state IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY state
ORDER BY state ASC;

State      StatePct
-----      --------
Alabama     7700.0
Alaska    103700.0
Arizona     4600.0
Arkansas   14800.0
California   700.0
Colorado    3700.0
Connecticut 5500.0
```

While I don't think this has a bearing it's SQLite3 on OSX.

Comment: You've discovered that SQLite does integer division.

Answer (score 2):

Ah the key! Casting the numerator as FLOAT and now it works. Thanks.

```
SELECT state, ROUND((CAST(count(call) AS FLOAT)/(Select count(call) FROM test) * 100.00), 2) AS StatePct
FROM test
WHERE state IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY state
ORDER BY state ASC;
```